# What packages are actively maintained/developed on github/bitbucket?

Tags: packages, package-writing

I would like to improve my TeX skills by following the development of actively developed packages. I findingwould like to give back by taking on some of the low hanging fruit among the issues/bug-reports of a package.

Any platform will do: Github, Bitbucket, Gitorious, Launchpad, etc...

Comment: Would you consider launchpad?

Comment: This question should probably be CW.

Comment: In our meta site, we have a [list of package maintainers who are TeX.sx residents](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181). We are updating that list in order to include public code repositories. It's worth a look. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Here a small list

- [draftinputlines](https://github.com/scmbradley/draftinputlines)
- [LaTeX3](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror)
- [matlab2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz)
- [tikzDevice](https://github.com/Sharpie/RTikZDevice)
- [mdframed](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed)
- [tufte-latex](https://github.com/godbyk/tufte-latex)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tex.sx celebrities who have github/bitbucket accounts.

- [Joseph Wright](https://bitbucket.org/josephwright)
- [Will Robertson](https://github.com/wspr)
- [Marco Daniel](https://github.com/marcodaniel)
- [Khaled Hosny](https://github.com/khaledhosny)
- [Seamus](https://github.com/scmbradley)
- [Martin Scharrer](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer)

My finding of these was rather unscientific. Please do add more.

Comment: I'm not sure about being a 'celebrity' :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: No, Joseph, you're an 'eminence'.

Answer (score 0):

[SageTeX](https://bitbucket.org/ddrake/sagetex) is hosted at Bitbucket.  It's a somewhat unusual package, though, since it's primarily about using mathematics software in document preparation (similar to [Sweave](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/)), so it may not be exactly what you are looking for.  Or maybe that makes it *more* what you are looking for...