# Looking for someone to help me finalize and distribute a class file

Tags: tikz-pgf, package-writing, documentclass-writing, contribute

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask but I don't know where else to go !

I've been working on the design of my lecture notes for a little while and now that I'm happy with the result, I would like to share it with everyone.

Problem is, the code needs to be cleaned/enhanced/tweaked and this goes way beyond my skills.

So, I'm looking for someone with the right skills to help me finalize this project. Hopefully someone here at stackexchange will like the look of my work and will be enthusiast enough to work with me. You can see the result here :

http://alexisfles.ch/example.pdf

And if you're too lazy to click on the link, I extracted one page for you :
[image: Beginning of chapter 4]

The little squares in the footer are clickable links to the corresponding chapters.

If my post shouldn't be here, thank you for directing me to the right place !

Edit: following @cfr and @Kpym advices, I've uploaded a MWE on github. The main style files are `nexus.sty` (page decoration) and `xeboiboites.sty` (a variation of `boiboites.sty` with a random effect). Everything is here : https://github.com/alexisflesch/nexus

Comment: Your link is broken (example.pdf)

Comment: You need to provide the class file and a minimal example. Screen shots of the result aren't really useful here. Anybody thinking of helping is going to want to know what the state of your code is. In particular, I'm not sure that a highly tailored class file is likely to be generally useful .... I have one I use for producing course readers and I'd doubt very much anyone else would want it. However, if you've *designed* the class to be of general use, that is different.

Comment: You can probably put your work on [GitHub](https://github.com/) in a way that you can give à link to the code and hope somebody can collaborate on it. There are already [other packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43874/9335) out there.

Comment: Ehm, if somebody finds the github repo, he will not know what to do. Please add a statement *why* the stuff is there and that you need some help. A license is also important.

Comment: I don't like the script font you used for "Definition" etc very much. Imho it doesn't fit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can think of better words than “it doesn't fit”, but I'm afraid they're not allowed on the site. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg A new option is needed `egregdoesnotlikeUrsula-Handschrift`.